# WAMP does not start after enabling/configuring SSPI

Tags: wamp, sspi

I am trying to get visitors' NT logon when they visit an intranet site. It appears the the SSPI module is what I'm looking for. But I can't get WAMP back up and running after installation. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I downloaded the mod and followed the install directions:

Copied mod_auth_sspi.so into C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\modules

Copied sspipkgs.exe into C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin (this wasn't in the instructions but I saw that step in another set of directions, I have same problem whether this is here or not)

Copied the line "LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so" and placed at the very end of other modules listed in the httpd.conf

Copied the following code:

```
<Directory "C:/SSPI">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "My Intranet"
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On

    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

into the very end of httpd.conf

Note: I figure the path in the Directory tag is not correct but am not sure what it should be since there that part is not covered in the install notes.

Then I restart services from the WAMP control panel and it cycles down through orange, then red, then back up to orange, but never gets back to green. Browsing to the site gives error 102. The Apache error log does provide any clues:

```
[Wed Apr 06 13:10:32 2011] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Apr 06 13:10:32 2011] [notice] Child 760: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Apr 06 13:10:33 2011] [notice] Child 760: Released the start mutex
[Wed Apr 06 13:10:34 2011] [notice] Child 760: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Apr 06 13:10:34 2011] [notice] Child 760: Child process is exiting
[Wed Apr 06 13:10:34 2011] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

I am running a WAMP server on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Apache 2.2.17

PHP 5.3.4

mod_auth_sspi-1.0.4-2.2.2.zip via http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/

Answer (score 1):

Go grab the 32bit version of WAMP

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/WampServer2.2a-x32.exe/download

It contains same version of everything-
Apache 2.2.21  Php 5.3.8  Mysql 5.5.16  XDebug 2.1.2  XDC 1.5  PhpMyadmin 3.4.5  SQLBuddy 1.3.3  webGrind 1.0

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify whether the above SourceFordge module works as expected because I don't have anything to test against, however, as far as WAMP is concerned, all I had to make the module be recognized and used by WAMP is just drop the module file into the mods folder.

Literally, that's all. Well, that and restart WAMP...

The instructions in the above download state that you need to edit the httpd.conf file with one of those "load_module" lines, but you apparently don't need to do this. Once you drop the file into the mod directory, restart WAMP and then left-click on the little WAMP icon in the Task Bar and hover the cursor over "Apache / Apache modules" to find "sspi_auth_module" as being already activated (it will probably be at the bottom of the list of available mods).

Again, this is just how it worked for me and I was using WAMP 2.2 (my version doesn't state anything about it being an alpha version in the "About" information, so I don't know if there's a version / functionality discrepancy there, but I hope all this helps someone in the future.)